# PHP character encoding problems

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, character-encoding

I need help with a character encoding problem that I want to sort once and for all. Here is an example of some content which I pull from a XML feed, insert into my database and then pull out.

As you can not see, a lot of special html characters get corrupted/broken.

How can I once and for all stop this? How am I able to support all types of characters, etc.?

I've tried literally every piece of coding I can find, it sometimes corrects it for most but still others are corrupted.

Comment: At what point do they appear "broken"? If you view the feed in a browser, do you see gibberish or the correct characters? Is there an "encoding" attribute in the XML declaration?

Comment: Just a quick thought, but can you tell us what character set your database tables are in?  If you do a "SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname;" on your tables in MySQL, you should see something at the end like "DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8".

Comment: Your code disappeared from the internet. Please add it again to your question otherwise this is going on to be deleted. Please take care to put the important part you ask about into the question itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;

/**
 * Encodes HTML safely for UTF-8. Use instead of htmlentities. 
 *
 * @param string $var 
 * @return string 
 */
function html_encode($var)
{
    return htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Those two rescued me and I think it is now *working*. I'll come back if I continue to encounter problems. Should I store it in the DB, eg as "&" or as "&"?

Comment: Why do you use character references although UTF-8 can encode overy character? Using `htmlspecialchars` to replace just the HTML special character will suffice, if you really have to replace them.

Answer (score 12):

To **absolutely once and for all** make sure you will never have problems with encoding again:

**Use UTF-8 everywhere and on everything!**

That is (if you use mysql and php):

- Set all the tables in your database to collation "utf8_general_ci" for example.
- Once you establish the database connection, run the following SQL query: "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
- Always make sure the settings of your editor are set to UTF-8 encoding.
- Have the following meta tag in the  section of your HTML documents:

  *<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">*

And couple of bonus tips:

- When you use PHP for string manipulation, use [the multibyte functions](http://php.net/mbstring).
- You might check http://docs.kohanaphp.com/core/utf8 as well at some point.

OR:

You can just use one simple server side configuration file that takes care of all encoding stuff. In this case you wont need header and/or meta tags at all or php.ini file modification. Just add your wanted character set encoding to .htaccess file and put it into your www root. If you want to fiddle with character set strings and use your php code for that - thats another story. Database collation must ofcourse be correct.

Footnote: UTF-8 is not *the* encoding solution its an *a* solution. It doesn't matter what character set/encoding one is using as long as the used environment has been taking to consideration.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite article about encodings from JoelOnSoftware: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Quite useful but still kinda not helping me so far :( I need some PHP specific advice

Comment: That Joel article is/was helpful, but it sort or side steps the fact that unicode support is "broken/wonky" is so many products that it's really hard to define what being a good citizen is. much less implement it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that an UTF-8 encoded text is interpreted with ISO 8859-1.

If you’re processing XML documents, you have to use the encoding given either in the `charset` parameter in [HTTP header field `Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) or in the `encoding` attribute in the [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-xmldecl). If none of both is given, the XML specification declares UTF-8 or UTF-16 as the [default character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding) and you have to use some [detection](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-guessing-no-ext-info).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the link you gave has data that is encoded in utf-8.  (Follow that link, then change the encoding of your browser to utf-8).

I sounds like you are having problems with inserting and retrieving from your database.  Make sure your database table has utf-8 set as the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

After you connect to the database, but before you do any transactions, execute the following line which makes sure all database communication is in UTF-8:

`mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $dbconn);`

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure your database's character encoding is set to support UTF-8. Secondly, PHP's [ICONV](https://www.php.net/iconv) is going to be your friend. Finally, ensure that your response headers are sending the proper character encoding (again, UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.utf8-encode.php) and [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.utf8-decode.php)?

Which one you use will depend entirely on how your data is encoded, which you don't specify, but they are quite useful for this kind of cases.