# local server ruins character encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, wamp, localserver

I need to learn all these encoding stuffs well. Because this is the third time I'm wasting my time with silly wrong encoding problems. Here is the problem:
I have a simple php file.

- File is in the format of UTF-8
- If I run my local server, it makes `ı => Ä±` and `ö =>  Ãœ`
- If I rename extension as HTML it works perfectly, so the problem is local server, definetely.

To correct this issue, I have done the following

1. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522956/strange-character-in-fresh-wamp-installation), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609509/php-mysql-e-written-as-a?lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825939/php-character-encoding-problems)
2. Double checked the file encoding, it's UTF-8
3. Added the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
4. Added the header inside php tag: `header("Content-type:text/html; charset: UTF-8");`
5. Added the internal encoding inside php tag `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');`
6. Corrected the line in *php.ini* file `default_charset = UTF-8`
7. Added the following in httpd.conf file: `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`
8. Everything is hard-coded, so I don't use database, it's not related to mysql encoding

I'm using WAMP, and machine is Windows 7 English. I'm completely exhausted, therefore, I really need help. 

Thanks.

Comment: What is your browser telling you about the received HTTP headers? It is useless to try to set them correctly without verifying this effort really changed something.

Comment: Wow, I found something here. It says `Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3` in **Request Headers** and `Content-Type:text/html; charset: UTF-8;charset=iso-8859-9` in **Response Headers**. How can I correct this and where is the problem?

Comment: The request header does not really matter. The response header definitely is wrong. If you correct it, things might work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found problem. I wrote

```
header("Content-type:text/html; charset: UTF-8");
```

After `Content-Type`, we need to have put `:` but after Charset we need to put equal sign `=` which was very frustrating for me. So,

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checks whether the document encoding is UTF-8 without BOM

and if does not work try `utf8_encode() and utf8_decode()`

**EDIT**

```
$text = "A strange string to pass, maybe with some ø, æ, å characters."; 

foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){ 
        echo mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $chr)." : ".$chr."<br>";    
 }
```

Comment: As far as I know, `utf8_encode() and utf8_decode()` is for strings to convert. But this is the whole document not a couple of strings. And yes it's without BOM.

Comment: Netbeans and Notepad++, but it's because of Response Header as Sven said in the comment above. I'm searching for the problem.

Comment: I think your problem is not wrong chars, it's more a wrong encoding http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-convert-encoding.php