# Best way to avoid encoding/collation char errors in no english web systems (PHP / Mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, collation

Since I started working with Apache, PHP/HTML/CSS/JS and databases such as MySQL, I always had to deal with latin charset problems.

I mean, starting from the database until the views are displayed in the browser screen, through all the many instances in which charset can be altered, I never had the chance of working with no problems, except with a Wamp/Xampp installation in localhost with Windows.

I always tried to set all charsets/encoding/collation in every place I could, but I always had different results, depending on the server (Linux, Windows).

I always check:

1) Database collation.

2) Table collation.

3) Column collation.

4) Apache charset configuration in httpd.conf

5) PHP charset configuration in php.ini

6) Individual php/html file encoding.

7) Addition of **meta** tag in every html with same encoding/charset.

8) Addition of "**header(... charset...)**" with same encoding/charset;

But in many circumstances, I keep on receiving unrecognized chars instead of accents and special latin symbols.
Sometimes it works ok in the screen, but I find problems with generated CSV/Excels, or as a JSON response from a webservice, etc.

I checked other posts like this one:
[PHP Character encoding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825939/php-character-encoding-problems)

I try to follow the tips, but I can't fix the problem in certain cases.

Tired of trying lots of things I always end up using functions such as **utf8_encode / decode**, or **iconv(...)**. 
Sometimes I even get the desired result only by using both **utf8_encode/decode**, one inside the other. Horrible.

Is there a tidy and easy way to resolve this without having to use those scary functions that leave the code untidy? 
Is the Operating System an issue? I tend to see more charset problems while running systems in Linux servers.

Comment: Dont use the latin character set. Use utf8.

Comment: You keep mentioning that you have issues, but you don't really tell us exactly what the issues are. I mean, "encoding problem" can mean a lot of different things and can have equally, or even more, different reasons. You should set _all_ tables and columns as UTF-8. You should also make sure that all your files (php-files etc) are stored in UTF-8.

Comment: Yes to add to @MagnusEriksson 's comment the files (php-files etc)  needs to be saved without byte order mark (BOM).. And make sure mysqli and pdo are using the uft8 charset it defaults into using latin1 charset.

Comment: sounds like you're doing everything correctly. can you give us a sample dodgy json you have a problem with?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: In a nutshell: you never want to *convert* encodings unless absolutely necessary (usually it is *not* necessary if you're responsible for everything). So you never want to see `utf8_en/decode`, `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv` anywhere in your code. If you get text in the wrong encoding from some external system (browser, database), there's a way to change that to receive text in the encoding you desire (HTTP headers, meta tags, database connection charset settings).

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good way, to set all of your encodings to the same value, otherwise, you're dealing with encoding issues.

## Database (specifically MySQL)

With MySQL for example, you're good with `utf8` or `utf8mb4`. Whatever fits your application better, can you read here: [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492). But you should set it for every database, table, and column. You shouldn't mix them up.

Set the connection encoding of MySQL to UTF-8. You can do this manually with `SET NAMES utf8`.

### mysqli

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

^1: [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) - PHP Docs

### PDO

```
<?php

$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "username", "password");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

^2: [PDO::setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) - PHP Docs

## Editor

Further, it also depends on the encoding you're using within your editor or IDE, respectively the encoding the file gets saved in. Most modern IDEs do use `utf8` as default, but some editors like Notepad++ need some extra configuration.

## Templates

Specify the character encoding for the HTML document with the `charset`-metatag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```